# kivy event dispatched but not received

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have the following files in an app

main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') # Kivy ver where the code has been tested!
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyW(Widget):
    def build(self):
        pass

class e3App(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyW()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    e3App().run()
```

e3.kv

```
#:import PlayListView playlistview
#:import SPlayView splayview

<MyW>:

    SPlayView:
        Button:
            on_touch_down:self.parent.buttonPressed()

    PlayListView:
```

splayview.py

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class SPlayView(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SPlayView,self).__init__()
        self.register_event_type('on_john')

    def buttonPressed(self):
        self.dispatch('on_john')

    def on_john(self):
        print 'event dispatched'
```

playlistview.py

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class PlayListView(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(PlayListView,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_john=self.on_john)

    def on_john(self):
        print 'hell'
```

When I press the button the event looks as if it is being dispatched, but it never arrives... What am I doing wrong, do i have to some way force the event to bubble or not get consumed, if so how.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `on_touch_down` if you won't handle collisions, it's not the same as `on_release` or similar event.

`build()` is a function in `App` class, next time use [`__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) and `super()`

Also you have to keep in mind that if you don't inherit from the class you want access the function from, it might not work - you inherit from `BoxLayout`, not from `SPlayView`.

When you want this behavior, I can come up with two approaches:

kv

```
#:import PlayListView playlistview
#:import SPlayView splayview

<MyW>:
    SPlayView:
        Button:

    PlayListView:
        Button:
            on_release:self.parent.buttonPressed()
```

1. function using `super()`

   ```
   class PlayListView(SPlayView):

       def __init__(self,**kwargs):
           super(PlayListView,self).__init__(**kwargs)
           self.bind(on_john=self.on_john)

       def on_john(self):
           print 'hell'
   ```

   splayview:

   ```
   from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
   from splayview import SPlayView
   class PlayListView(SPlayView):

       def __init__(self,**kwargs):
           super(PlayListView,self).__init__(**kwargs)
           # self.bind(on_john=self.on_john)

       def on_john(self, *args):
           super(PlayListView,self).on_john()
           print 'hell'
   ```
2. function using `bind()`

   You can't have functions with the same name

   ```
   from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
   from splayview import SPlayView
   class PlayListView(SPlayView):

       def __init__(self,**kwargs):
           super(PlayListView,self).__init__(**kwargs)
           self.bind(on_john=self.on_johnn)

       def on_johnn(self, *args):
           print 'hell'
   ```

   There you have to keep in mind that the bound function will be executed *first* and then your event e.g. `hell` will be printed earlier than `event dispatched`

However if you want to call some function from `SPlayView`, you don't have to bind other functions to it, just call `YourClass.function()` in the `on_john` event. I'm a little bit confused, so I hope you meant this. O.o

Comment: Thank you , much appreciated